# Autogeneration column in list

Tags: list

I want to create a field in list whose value should be autogenerated.
Like 'Ticket ID' , which get autogenerated or populated when item get created with 'INC0001' , 'INC0002' so on. (INC000 need to be added as prefix)
Can i acheive it by SPD 2010 workflow or javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many approaches (workflow, calculated column, event handler, custom feature etc) but you may try with wrokflow or calculated column.

**Just check below article for workflow:**

1. http://dlairman.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/add-a-unique-auto-incrementing-column-to-a-sharepoint-list/
2. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9ff1dc1b-140f-4199-a843-3b7b7388b6da/how-to-generate-auto-increment-id-for-sharepoint-list-item-using-calculated-column?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

**Check this for calculated column:**

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/sharepoint-how-to-create-an-auto-incrementing-number-field-for-use-in-a-custom-id-part-1.aspx

Let us know if you face any problem in above approach.

Comment: Thanks Karthik,
for link http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9ff1dc1b-140f-4199-a843-3b7b7388b6da/how-to-generate-auto-increment-id-for-sharepoint-list-item-using-calculated-column?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Can you let me know "new value" configuration as calculated

Comment: @user21081, as per that link "New_id" will be having your required value like INC0002, now assign the "New_id" to current item's 'Ticket ID'.